# P ∧ (R ⇒ (¬(Q ∧ P)) equivalent to (P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ ((P ∧ (¬R)) ∧ Q), I need help please?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

> Prove that $$P ∧ (R ⇒ (¬(Q ∧ P))$$ is equivalent to $$(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ ((P ∧ (¬R)) ∧ Q).$$

This is how far I got, and then I am completely stuck.

$$P∧(¬R∨(¬Q∨¬P))=(P∧¬R)∨(P∧¬Q)∨(P∧¬P)$$

It would be great if I can get some help on the other way round, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

HINTS

The $P \land \neg P$ at the end is a contradiction, and disjuncting that with anything makes the contradiction go away.

Also, start with the RHS expression and try simplifying that one as well .. see if they can meet 'in the middle'

Comment: So that left with (P∧¬R)v(P∧¬Q) which I couldnt see any further simplifying, or are there still, please point out, cheers

Comment: @stevielol Right. So like I said, now start with the other sentence and see if you can simplify that one to $(P \land \neg R) \lor (P \land \neg Q)$ as well.

Comment: Doesnt it u have to render (P∧¬R)v(P∧¬Q) exactly == (P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ ((P ∧ (¬R)) ∧ Q) for the equivalencies? Sorry I just started recently so I havent fully grasp the concept

Comment: @stevielol (P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ (¬R))=P ∧((¬Q) ∨ (¬R))= P ∧((¬Q) ∨ (¬R))∧(Q ∨ (¬Q))= P ∧((¬Q) ∨ ((¬R) ∧ Q))=(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ ((P ∧ (¬R)) ∧ Q)

Comment: @user529760 Wher did u derive P ∧((¬Q) ∨ (¬R))= P ∧((¬Q) ∨ (¬R))∧(Q ∨ (¬Q)) from ??

Comment: @stevielol because (Q ∨ (¬Q))=true.

Comment: @user529760 thank you for the help

Comment: @stevielol you're welcome!

Comment: @user529760 just one more question, if (Q ∨ (¬Q))=true/1, how is (Q ∨ (¬Q))= Q?

Comment: @stevielol I think I used too many parentheses, so you got lost. Let me repeat my equalities (this time I use less parentheses):\begin{align}(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ ¬R)&=P ∧(¬Q ∨ ¬R)\\&=P ∧(¬Q ∨ ¬R)∧(¬Q ∨ Q)\\&= P ∧(¬Q ∨ (¬R ∧ Q))\\&=(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ ((P ∧ ¬R) ∧ Q)\end{align}

Comment: @user529760 But how did u get (Q ∨ ¬Q)==Q? As you said, shouldnt Q ∨ (¬Q)==T/1?

Comment: @stevielol $(Q ∨ ¬Q)$ is not $Q$. I used the distributive property:$$(A ∨ B)∧(A ∨ C)= A ∨ (B ∧ C)$$

Comment: ok , many thanks